# Validation not performed in a Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to use annotations in classes. I use `javax.validation.constrants.*` for annotations.

```
public final class EmailCredential implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1246534146345274432L;

    @NotBlank(message = "Sender must not be empty.")
    @Email
    private final String sender;

    @NotBlank(message = "Subject must not be empty.")
    private final String subject;

/// getters setters

}
```

None of them are working as expected. Meaning that when a below API gets called, annotations should throw error if annotated field is invalid. It looks like there is no annotation to check fields. How properly can I use annotations in a normal class?

controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/email/credentials", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, Object> emailCredentials(@RequestBody EmailCredential emailCredential) {
        return emailService.setCredentials(emailCredential);
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "working as expected".

Comment: Are you expecting an error should be through from bean and you can use that to throw the custom exception or in your HTML/JSp you are unable to view the error message?

Comment: @mallikarjun I expect an error from the bean. My application is a resource server. It doesn't have view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the validation has to be specified to be triggered.
So add the [`@Valid`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html) annotation on the parameter(s) that you want to validate such as :

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
// ...
@PostMapping(value = "/email/credentials", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, Object> emailCredentials(@RequestBody @Valid EmailCredential emailCredential) {
        return emailService.setCredentials(emailCredential);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you also know what exception class is being thrown so I can put that in my rest error resolver?

Comment: You are welcome. Sure. You should see  a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` But the best way to check that is to run the code !

Answer (score 2):

According to Spring Boot official documentation : [**Validating Form Input**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)

**You should indicate that your `EmailCredential` need to be validated using the annotation `@Valid`**

Here's an example from documentation :

```
package hello;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;


@Controller
public class WebController implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/results").setViewName("results");
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showForm(PersonForm personForm) {
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String checkPersonInfo(@Valid PersonForm personForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "form";
        }

        return "redirect:/results";
    }
}
```